# FTP last modified time incorrect

Tags: ftp, debian

I have a debian virtual server. I connect via either:

- WinSCP using SFTP
- FileZilla using FTP

The problem I am having is that when editing a file FileZilla always adds the incorrect 'Last Modified' - 2 hours

The strange thing is that WinSCP works perfectly. Is this a setting in FileZilla or on my server.

I use Pure-FTPd if this helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible the user under which the FTP daemon is running has the wrong timezone set.  Check if the system timezone was updated, but the server not rebooted / ftp daemon / inetd not restarted.  Depending on which user the FTP daemon runs as, it could be that account which has the wrong timezone setup.

Comment: Worked perfect thanks.
Reference: http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/213
This command: /usr/bin/tzselect